# Explain a pun please

Tags: puns

I think it's the right place to ask. English is not my native, so while I'm able to understand a majority of puns I come acrossб this one puzzles me:

[Here's a link to the image.](http://indy100.independent.co.uk/image/28166-4ao1gu.JPG)

Comment: The pun in question is essentially the same one that lies at the core of the schoolyard chant, "You're nose is very runny and you think it's very funny but it's not."

Comment: @SvenYargs the funny thing: I would never understand this chant's punch if I have had heard it out of the context of my question. Mostly because the word "snot" wasn't the part of my vocabulary. I've took the test at [vocabularysize.com](http://vocabularysize.com) right now and it says "You know at least 23,100 English word families!". That's too much even for my ego lol. But there is a difference between "to know/understand" and "to employ" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Omg, I'm such a slowpoke. It turned out to be simple. Got it right after pressing post button.

It's

> "pun skill", obviously.

Comment: Well, I learned that using >! might hide text in a blockquote until it's hovered....

Comment: Ditto. And there's a solution  on mobile browser and android application too.

Comment: @jungle_mole   :) I liked that one. Also took me about 3 seconds, was puzzled at first...

Answer (score -1):

I think Pun is a literary term which means playing with words by using Homonyms (It means each of two or more words having the same spelling or pronunciation but different meanings and origins) for example Fare & Fair.